# Potential memory leak after CFSocketCreateWithNative

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, cfsocket

This is driving me mad! What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Can you please put the actual text of the code into your question so that it's searchable for future readers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the reference hasn't been modified by another thread. Assign the socket to a local variable on creation, modify it, set the property, and release the local variable:

```
CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(...);
if (socket) {
    ...
    self.listeningSocket = socket;
    CFRelease(socket);
}
```